# What is the probability of getting the highest score on the test?

Tags: probability, statistics

If you take a test and your overall score is in the 91 National Percentile, what is the probability that you got the highest grade in the class if 12 other people took the same test? I hope my question makes sense. I'm trying to figure this out but I'm lacking in knowledge. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the probability that all 12 are below the 91% threshold is
$(0.91)^{12}$

Comment: Sounds good to me! Thanks!

Comment: Of course this answer assumes independence of results for different individuals; but that may be doubtful if you are all from the same class.

Comment: @paw88789 fair enough.